# If $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are roots of the equation $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$ then find the least value of $[|z_1+z_2|]+1$ ([.] denotes G.I.F.)

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, roots

> If $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are roots of the equation $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$ then find the least value of $[|z_1+z_2|]+1$ ([.] denotes G.I.F.)

**My Attempt:**

By applying sum of GP, I am getting $z^5-1=0$

That means, $z$ is 5th root of unity except $1$.

Thus, $z=e^{\frac{i2k\pi}5}$, where $k=1,2,3,4$

I took $k=1,2$ and let that to be $z_1,z_2$

Thus, $|z_1+z_2|$ came out to be $2\cos\frac\pi5$. Its greatest integer is 1. So, final answer is 2.

But the given answer is $1$.

It means lower value of $|z_1+z_2|$ exists.

How to find that without checking every combination of $z_1,z_2?$

Comment: You want $(z_1+z_2)$ to cancel out ( not add up ) , thus giving a Smaller Integer Part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the roots in the complex plane.  You can then draw lines between them to find the midpoint with the smallest modulus by inspection.  The modulus of the sum of two is twice the midpoint.

Comment: Mid point with the smallest modulus is coming out to be zero, right?

Comment: Not until you take the greatest integer function, but I believe so.  I believe one of the pairs with smallest modulus is $e^{2\pi/5}$ and $e^{8\pi/5}$

Comment: From the diagram, my guess would have been $k=1,3$

Comment: It doesn't matter which ones you pick, just that they are the right number of spots apart.  The modulus will be the same for any pair that are not neighbors because of the symmetry.  If you add in the point $z=1$ you have a regular pentagon centered at the origin.

Comment: Yes, thankyou...